# JMeter : Should we keep "Embedd HTML resource" checkbox enable for load test?

Tags: jmeter, embedded-resource

My scenario is to test response time for any web page which has many resources like png, jpg, css, etc embedded.

I need help in understanding whether we should enable or not `"Embedd HTML resources"` checkbox while running performance test in JMeter based on best practice to be followed to get realistic response time.

A) If I have **recorded** script then these resources are recorded in script.

So questions are:

1. are we required to use exclusion pattern or not?

2. should we disable all resources recorded from script and simply enable this check    box for "Embedd HTML resources"?

3. should we keep recorded resources in the script and disable the check box for "Embedd HTML resources"?

B) If we have **created** script manually by adding Http Sampler for each web page, then as a best practice should be enable / select checkbox "Embedd HTML resources".

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Holding on to recorded samplers for static content is quite atrocius. It wastes valuable Jmeter resources. Any mean values that are taken across samplers will be skewed by the usually quick response times of those samples. (Although such mean values are not very useful in general, under most circumstances.)

Answer (score 0):

Choosing whether to include embedded (static) content is dependent on your individual circumstances. There is no 'best practice'.

Two examples:

1. If I am running a test for a webserver that, when it goes live, will be behind a CDN then for my load testing I could reasonably decide to not send static content on the basis that these requests are going to be handled by the CDN and will never reach my backend webserver. If I *did* send static content in this scenario then I would be simulating an unrealistic load.
2. But if my application was not using a CDN and instead had, perhaps, 2 of its own content accelerators then in order to test this setup I would want to be driving static content requests into this network layer (where the accelerators are positioned). If I *did not* send static content in this scenario then I would be generating an unrealistic load.

There are many, many other factors that can affect why you might want to include or not include embedded resources - only you can make the final choice.

In addition: Consider using a [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) where you are trying to simulate static content calls.

Comment: Note. 'How' you include them (whether you should record them or not) is simply a matter of taste - but I would say that the easiest method here is to remove or filter the requests from your recording and then to check the 'include embed. resource...' checkbox later. This will automatically parse the page and dynamically send any static content request that are included in the page response. If you decided, however, that you wanted to use the recorded values then you should *not* check the 'include...' checkbox, this would create duplication.